# Mapping multiple form inputs of the same name into a JavaScript object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an HTML form similar to this.

```html
<label for="person-firstname">First Name</label>
<input type="text" id="person-firstname" name="person-firstname"/>

<label for="person-lastname">Last Name</label>
<input type="text" id="person-lastname" name="person-lastname" />

<label for="person-phone">Phone</label>
<input type="text" id="person-phone" name="person-phone" />

<!-- Button will add the same input as above -->
<button type="button" onclick="addAnotherPersonSection()">+ Add Another Person</button>

<!-- More HTML of different section of the overall form -->

<label for="person-terms">Agree to Terms and Conditions</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="person-terms" name="person-terms" />

<label for="person-initals">Initals</label>
<input type="text" id="person-initals" name="person-initals" />
```

What I'm trying to do is map out the input into an object with the key name as the name of the input and value being the input text.

```
{
  "Persons":[{
    "person-firstname":input.value,
    "person-lastname":input.value,
    "person-phone":input.value,
    "person-terms":input.value,
    "person-initals":input.value
  }, {
    "person-firstname":input.value,
    "person-lastname":input.value,
    "person-phone":input.value,
    "person-terms":input.value,
    "person-initals":input.value
  }]
}
```

The problem is naming the key of the object as "person-firstname" instead of when **$("input[name^=business]").serializeArray();** creates it the key is named "name" and is structured wrong.

```
    { name: "person-firstname", value:input},
    { name: "person-lastname", value:input}
```

I'm just looking for a JavaScript or jQuery solution to create a dynamic object based on multiple inputs of the same name. Also, have control of the key name.

Comment: Given that the order of properties in an object are not (and can not be) guaranteed, for what purpose do you want to do this?

Comment: I'm sending a JSON object over to SQL server and using it to insert into the DB. Im using OPENJSON to map the JSON to the right columns and need to insert a row for each person.

Comment: Which doesn't explain why they need to be in a specific order, unless you're using DB column indexes instead of DB column names... you wouldn't do that, would you?

Comment: In the end I just need the object to be structured like how I show it in the question. I guess the order of how they appear doesn't matter as long as the there is a Persons array and has the key and values shown. And I get that from a form that can have one or more person.

Comment: If you want it in arbitrary order (as opposed to alphabetic/DOM order), then you'll have to code this.  Eg you can add an array with mappings, `var mappings = [ ["firstname", "person-firstname"], ["initials", "person-intials"] ]` then loop through each mapping to get the field name and the property name.

Comment: Or - you can achieve this by adding `data-` attributes to the inputs, eg `<input name='firstname' data-key='person-firstname' order='5' ...` then handle the serialisation based on the attributes.

Comment: I edited the question to remove the part of ordering the object. The main focus is to just be able to map out an object from the form as structured in the question. When there is one or more person inputs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The crux of the problem is that you can't have multiple form fields with the same name. If you do, that's called a "naming collision" which will bust native functionality of an HTML form. But you can use a sort of template-like logic and generate variant names that make sense base on the number of people that are added to the HTML form. My example may not be what you're looking for exactly, but it's what I came up with:

[image]

https://codesandbox.io/s/admiring-hypatia-30lrv